# Get all WooCommerce subscriptions

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I a need to create a wordpress template to collect all Woocommerce subscriptions, but I'm having trouble with the documentation. I need to know which files to import and which function to call.

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update - You can use multiple ways:**

1. The built-in function `wcs_get_subscriptions()` which accepts [specific arguments](https://github.com/pronamic/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/main/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/wcs-functions.php#L417-L432). In your case, to get all subscriptions, you will use:

   $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(['subscriptions_per_page' => -1]);

You will get an array of Subscription protected objects where you can use on each object the `WC_Data` `get_data()` method, to access the data:

```
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(['subscriptions_per_page' => -1]);

// Loop through subscriptions protected objects
foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
    // Unprotected data in an accessible array
    $data = $subscription->get_data();
 
    print_r( $data ); // Display the subscription raw data array
}
```

Related: [Get Subscription Product author of a Woocommerce subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054276/get-subscription-product-author-of-a-woocommerce-subscription)

---

2. You can also use **a SQL query** to get all subscriptions

A SQL query can be lighter and allows more filtering. This way you can get only the required data in a more effective way.

As subscriptions are a Wordpress custom post type, You can get all subscriptions IDs first. Then in a foreach loop you will be able to get the `WC_subscription` object.

```
global $wpdb;

// get all subscriptions IDS
$subscriptions_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts 
    WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_subscription'
");

// Loop through subscriptions Ids
foreach($subscriptions_ids as $subscription_id){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Subscription object
    $subscription = new WC_Subscription( $subscription_id );

    $data = $subscriptions->get_data();
 
    print_r( $data ); Display the subscription raw data (unprotected accessible array)
}
```

Then with the **`$subscription`** object and the **`$subscription_id`** you will be able to do what you want, using **`WC_Subscription`** methods to get the desired data or the using subscription ID on dedicated functions.

---

Official developer Documentation:

- [**Introduction to Subscriptions Developer Documentation**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/)
- [**Subscriptions Data Structures & Storage**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/data-structure/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried your solution and it brought the created subscriptions as products, what if I want to loop through user subscriptions, what users have subscribed to? For example, I have Product A and Product B all subscription products. Product B has 3 users subscribed, I want to loop through 3 users' subscriptions and not subscription products. How can that be achieved any method? Thank you

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue Sorry but this code goes through users subscriptions and not subscription products.

Comment: I have only one active subscription and the plugin is printing twice in a loop. Please help me understand why. I have two subscription products but only one user subscription. Why is your code printing datat twice? If it was looping users subscriptions I would expect it to print once

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue See at the beginning of my answer: *"…which accepts [specific arguments](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/wcs-functions.php#L425-L438)."* … You need to set an additional argument `, 'subscription_status' =>  'wc-active'` or `, 'subscription_status' =>  'active'` (One of the 2 is the good one)…

Comment: Thanks for your solution actually it has helped me. I have used your code and the client is satisfied and happy. I was missing the point of wc_active. Thank you,  This is the best answer

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue I know, just saying…

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in function wcs_get_subscriptions($args) and pass the following $args

```
$args = array( 'subscriptions_per_page' => -1 );

$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions( $args );
```

You can even filter by subscription status also in the arguments.