# Get Subscription Product author of a Woocommerce subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, author, woocommerce-subscriptions

How can I iterate through all current active woo subscriptions and print the user ID of the user who published the product related to each active subscription (PHP)? I think something like this will give just the subscriptions:

```
$args = array( 'subscriptions_per_page' => -1, 'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // WC orders post type
                'post_status' => 'wc-active' );
            $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions( $args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will query all active subscriptions to get the author Id (that published the product of the active subscription):

```
// Get all active subscriptions
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions( array(
    'subscriptions_per_page' => -1,
    'subscription_status' => array('active') // Active subscriptions
) );

// 1) Loop through quieried active subscriptions
foreach($subscriptions as $subscription)
{
    // 2) Loop through subscription items
    foreach( $subscription->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) 
    {
        // Get the subscription product author
        $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $item->get_product_id());
        // Display
        echo $author_id . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Tested and works.